# get file name from Protractor test

Tags: typescript, protractor, mocha.js

I have many tests in my suites, and I want to print out the file name when, either running tests, or include the filename in all test failures.

I can print out the specs with `console.log(config.specs)` in `browser.getProcessedConfig()`, but it only shows with the glob pattern, whereas I want the full file name. Ive tried `config.suites`, but it prints out ALL suites, not just the one run in the test.

conf.shared.ts

```
await browser.getProcessedConfig().then(async function(config: any) {
        });
        console.log(config.specs)
        console.log(config.suites)
        return config.specs;
```

output from config.specs

```
 '../../../../lib/tests/home/**/*.myparam*.js'
```

output from config.suites

```
 mysuite:
    '../../../../lib/tests/home/**/market/**/*.*.myfilename.js',
  mysuite2:
        '../../../../lib/tests/home/**/market2/**/*.*.myfilename.js',
  mysuite3:
        '../../../../lib/tests/home/**/market3/**/*.*.myfilename.js',
  mysuite4:
        '../../../../lib/tests/home/**/market4/**/*.*.myfilename.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `conf.js` add this to `onPrepare`

```
onPrepare() {

        /**
         *  Set global environment configuration
         */
        Object.defineProperty(global, '__stack', {
            get: function () {
                let orig = Error.prepareStackTrace;
                Error.prepareStackTrace = function (_, stack) {
                    return stack;
                };
                let err = new Error;
                Error.captureStackTrace(err, arguments.callee);
                let stack = err.stack;
                Error.prepareStackTrace = orig;
                return stack;
            }
        });

        // returns name of the file from which is called
        Object.defineProperty(global, '__file', {
            get: function () {
                let path = __stack[1].getFileName();
                try { //*nix OSes
                    return path.match(/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+$/)[0];
                } catch (error) { //Windows based OSes
                    return path.match(/[^\\]+\\[^\\]+$/)[0];    
                }
            }
        });
        // returns function name from which is called
        Object.defineProperty(global, '__function', {
            get: function () {
                return __stack[1].getFunctionName();
            }
        });
        // returns line number of the position in code when called
        Object.defineProperty(global, '__line', {
            get: function () {
                return __stack[1].getLineNumber();
            }
        });

    },
```

and then if you run this anywhere in your framework (specs or page objects)

```
console.log(__file);
console.log(__function);
console.log(__line);
```

you'll get something like this accrodingly

```
// test.spec.js
// funcName()
// 56
```

Obviously you can adjust the code for your needs

Comment: The above solution give me error: `Cannot find name '__stack'`. 

Also can you explain how the above solution is different from using just `console.log(__filename)` ?